# How to set the base URL for FCKeditor image upload service to domain name

Tags: php, fckeditor

I have FCKEditor for uploading images to newsletter, but the images in the editor are placed with relative path.

```
/uploads/media/1.jpg
```

How can I enforce to use

```
http://www.example.org/uploads/media/1.jpg
```

when creating the HTML content inside the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in "fck/editor/filemanager/connectors/php/config.php"

set this param :

$Config['UserFilesPath']  = "http://www.example.org/"

Comment: in comments they indicate relative path